Cost raster does not start with zero
I used processing.run('grass7:r.cost', params) to create a cost raster starting at one or several points along a street-raster-layer. Each cell is 1m² and the algorithm is supposed to accumulate (distance)cost up to 400m. Sometimes this works as intended, sometimes the minimum value is not (roughly) 0 as can be seen below. Is it possible that there occurs some looping or strange behaviour in dead ends?
QGIS Version is 3.34.11 LTR. Rasters used are valid, points have been snapped to original street network. CRS and extent should be identical between all rasters.


I have also used the identification tool in QGis, which tells me that the first raster pixel is not near 0
